# Задача на листы в хаскеле

Tags: haskell

Нужно написать функцию которая буде удалять элементы листа с индексами которые являются простыми. Главная проблема в том что я не понимаю как работать с индексами в хаскеле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обращаться к элементу списка по индексу позволяет оператор `!!`:

```hs
Prelude> "test" !! 1
'e'
Prelude> ["x", "y", "z"] !! 2
"z"
```

Но делать этого вам не придется, хотя бы потому, что каждое такое обращение занимает линейное время.

Проще всего будет использовать генератор списка. Например, так можно отфильтровать элементы с нечетными индексами.

```hs
Prelude> [x | (i, x) <- zip [0 ..] ['a' .. 'z'], even i]
"acegikmoqsuwy"
```

или то же самое в виде композиции преобразований

```
Prelude> map snd . filter (even . fst) . zip [0 ..] $ ['a' .. 'z']
"acegikmoqsuwy"
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или `even` проверяет на четность? ТС вместо `even` нужно будет поставить проверку на простое число

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Верно, програма оставляет четные индексы и отфильтровывает нечетные, как я и сказал. По словам ТС, у него проблемы с индексами, а не с проверкой на простоту, значит сможет адаптировать пример под себя, изменив предикат.

Comment: Прошу прощения за неудачную формулировку. Я понял, что Вы сделали, просто решил(возможно, напрасно) привлечь к этому факту внимание ТС.